# Exclude nav-item from collapse in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I have the following structure of the navigation menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-transparent navbar-dark fixed-top" style="position:absolute">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav" id="login">
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" style="font-weight:300;"  href=""><i class="fas fa-user fa-sx"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</a>
    </li>    
  </ul>   
</nav>
```

As you see due to mr-auto link 1, link 2, link 3 placed in the left side of the menu and "login" placed in the right side. On the small screens my menu collapses including nav-item "login". So, is it possible to excldude specific nav-item from collapse?